# How to show this equality for a power serie?

Tags: power-series

Let $S(z) = \sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n z^n$ be a power serie with radius of convergence 1, such that $$S(x) \sim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
I'm trying to show that, for every polynomial $P$,
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} (1-x) \sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n x^n P(x^n) = \int_0^1 P(t) dt.$$
For now, i have no idea how to proceed... Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It might make sense to note that the coefficients $a_n$ of $S$ are all $1$.

Comment: Hint : Note that if $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^s b_i x^i$, then $$(1-x) \sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n x^n P(x^n)=\sum_{i=0}^s b_i\frac{1-x}{1-x^{1+i}}(1-x^{1+i})S(x^{1+i})$$

Comment: @K.defaoite No, for example if $f(x) = 1+x+\frac1{1-x}$ then $f(x)\sim\frac1{1-x}$.